# The type or namespace name 'Ajax' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I got an old project which consist of three different projects. When I am trying to build the project I am getting this error message:

```
"The type or namespace name 'Ajax' could not be found (are you missing a using    
directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

I have found solution for missing project or namespace online but it looks like I am missing some default library.

The code looks like this:

```
//Ajax method to Check for existing file name
[Ajax.AjaxMethod()]
public DataTable CheckSearchName(string searchname){
   // code goes here
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the problem was solved. I was missing a reference for this project. I found a Ajax.dll file in my website's bin folder. Then all I had to do is just adding a reference to this file (Website/Project > Add reference > Browse > (Browse to Bin folder) > Ajax.dll

That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the really old Microsoft AJAX.NET library from the .NET 1.1/2.0 days.

See here: [Microsoft AJAX.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479042.aspx), which has a download link to the class library: [Ajax.NET Professional](http://www.ajaxpro.info/).

Comment: You are right. This project was originally built on .Net 2.0 framework. One question: I think I already have Ajax installed in my machine (VS 2008 is showing Ajax Extension & Ajax Control Toolkit) why would I need to install another Ajax then?

Comment: You would need to have whatever class library this project is expecting as a reference in the project and then the namespace from that library added in the class above (or entire project) that is referencing it.

Comment: Can you please explain that a little bit more? I added a reference to both AjaxPro.2.dll & AjaxPro.dll but none of them seems to be working. Do I have to use "Using" too? If yes how would I do that?

Comment: Try adding "using Ajax;" (minus the quotes) at the top of that class in your code sample.

Comment: nah didn't help :( btw I already have a Ajax.dll in my Bin folder and there is NO Reference folder (for the website, there are two other projects, they've got their own Reference folder though)

Comment: I am not near an ASP.NET web project at the moment, but I believe references on web projects are in the project's properties. Right-click the web project and go to properties. There should be a references section within, you may be missing the reference there.

You only need the reference in the projects that need to utilize the library.